# Can not select my 'deployment projects' (VSTS projects) in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have successfully linked my Azure account to my Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) account. Next I wanted to configure in Azure a deployment for one of my VSTS project (ASP.NET MVC).

After choosing VSTS as source, Azure required to choose a VSTS project from the displayed list. But my list is empty!! (I do have projects in VSTS however).

What do I have to do that my projects are displayed in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That feature is used for git repository, so there must be a git repository in a team project of your VSTS.

You can create a new team project with git version control system or a new git repository in a team project with TFVC version control system.

[image]
[image]