# Azure Team Services Deployment Source

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-devops

I've been at this for hours, can't seem to link my Team Services project with Azure. The screenshot below show that no projects are pulling up! I've tried using Azure Portal to link my account, setting up an endpoint on Team Services, etc. Any ideas?

[image: Azure Team Services Deployment Source]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39874840/can-not-select-my-deployment-projects-vsts-projects-in-azure). There must be a git repository in a team project of your VSTS.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But why? Azure didn't give any help during the setup process. Is there some documentation that explains it?